# Android: onBackPressed() does not work?

Tags: android

I've an Activity with just these methods:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_week);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

that shows carette in the action bar, and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

'couse I want to finish(); this activity after pressing carette simbol. But nothing happens when i press back button with my finger. What's wrong?

Comment: leave just the line: `finish();` onBackPressed()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to finish the activity when option bar's back button clicked you need to add following code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Hardware back will work by default. You can remove

> onBackPressed()

method or edit as like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the statement: `this.finish()` is sufficient to do this..

You can delete this one: `super.onBackPressed();`